# What is the meaning of the expression "異質の危険"?

Tags: expressions

I've been reading some documents on documents by various political parties, and have seen the term "異質の危険" used by 日本共産党 a few times now, but cannot work out what it means.

Whenever I've seen it, it's always surrounded by quotation marks, such as

> 安倍晋三政権が今国会へ提出し、国家安全保障会議（日本版ＮＳＣ）設置法案とともに成立をねらう秘密保護法案に対し、反対の世論が広がっています。秘密保護法案は、外交、防衛など日本の「安全保障に関する情報」を保護するため、「行政機関の長」が「特定秘密」を指定し、それを漏らした公務員などに「懲役１０年」もの重罰を科す弾圧法です。情報に接近しようとした国民や報道機関も対象です。秘密保護法は、「安全保障」を名目に、広範な行政情報を国民から隠す、文字通りの「軍事立法」です。これまでにはない **“異質の危険”** は明らかです。

and

> 日本中の原発が停止した“原発稼働ゼロ”の期間は７００日になろうとしている。原発がなくても電力が足りていることは、この月日が証明している。ひとたび大事故を起こしたら、その被害が空間的にも時間的にも制限なく広がる **「異質の危険」** を持つ原発と人類は共存できない。

I've tried to find other examples of this term in databases of parallel texts, and definitions of it in Japanese, but cannot find any kind of explanation. I suppose that a literal translation might be "heterogeneous danger" or "foreign danger", but I cannot work out how this makes any sense in the context of the paragraphs such as the above.

Would anyone be able to shed any light on this phrase?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think 異質の危険 is a commonly used combination, but in this context, 異質の roughly means *qualitatively different*.

While there are varying degrees of dangerous things in the world, the authors are basically saying that 秘密保護法案/原発 is incomparably, enormously dangerous, and putting it simply as "more dangerous than others" (quantitatively) is not enough.